# Why does vertex merging cause non manifold geometry?

Tags: modeling, geometry

I am having issues with some non-manifold geometry.. I understand there are a few types or a few sources of non-manifold geometry, but I can't find the exact issue with my model..

I noticed most of it, if not all, was located where I merged vertices together. Why would this cause non-manifold geometry? I thought the goal of the merging process was precisely to make sure I had a unified mesh?

Here is the file in question, maybe I missed something:

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Merging vertices can still leave interior faces, or double edges. Please add some images (and perhaps your.blend) if you want more specific answers :).

Comment: Thanks for the response! There don't seem to be any interior faces and I have already tried to merge by distance to fix double edges but there doesn't seem to be any... How do I add my .blend to the post?

Comment: Hey :). You can try gdrive/dropbox or our local [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: @JachymMichal Awesome, went ahead and did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mesh contains flipped faces, which is considered non-manifold geometry.
It's probably not caused by merging vertices, and it's easy to repair

1. Select all faces
2. Go *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*
3. Done.

After this, there are still some non-manifold vertices on the outer rim, because the mesh isn't 'closed'.

[image]

Comment: Amazing. I thought I had already fixed those... Apparently I hadn't! Thank you for the help, cheers

Comment: Glad to be of help :). Good luck with your project.